# Why does **0.5 appear to be more efficient than sqrt()

Tags: r, performance, square-root, sqrt, exponentiation

I have tried measuring the speed of these two ways for taking square root:

```
> system.time(expr = replicate(10000, 1:10000 ** (1/2)))
##   user  system elapsed 
##  0.027   0.001   0.028 
> system.time(expr = replicate(10000, sqrt(1:10000)))
##   user  system elapsed 
##  3.722   0.665   4.494
```

If the `sqrt()` function cannot compete with `** 0.5`, why do we need such a function?

(system is OS X Yusemite, and R version is 3.1.2)

Comment: See `?Syntax` for operator precedence. Exponentiation `^` has higher precedence than sequence operator `:`. Compare `1:4 ^ (0.5)`; `1:(4 ^ (0.5))`; `(1:4) ^ (0.5)`

Comment: Before benchmarking two alternatives you should always check that they give identical results.

Answer (score 13):

You forgot important parentheses. Here are the timings after correcting that:

```
system.time(expr = replicate(10000, (1:10000) ** (1/2)))
#user  system elapsed 
#4.76    0.32    5.12 
system.time(expr = replicate(10000, sqrt(1:10000)))
#user  system elapsed 
#2.67    0.57    3.31
```

Answer (score 8):

To add to @Roland's answer, you fell into the [Operators precedence](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/Syntax.html) "trap". `^` comes before `:` ("*`**` is translated in the parser to `^`*" as per documentation of `?"**"`)

What really happened is

```
`:`(1, 10000 ** (1/2))
```

That means that first you've run `**` and only then `1:..`

A tip for the future, try to debug your code before running sophisticated operations, for example, testing

```
1:5 ** (1/2)
## [1] 1 2
sqrt(1:5)
## [1] 1.000000 1.414214 1.732051 2.000000 2.236068
```

Would reveal the issue.

Comment: ** is a somewhat common way to indicate exponentiation in other languages. That is probably how they came up with it.